# Help to reproduce this box?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I'm trying to reproduce this box but with a title box placed on the top right and slightly rotated.

I am not satisfied with the results: the right and left border rules are not very parallel and the corners are not rounded in the same way. Can you help me please ?  [image: What I want]
[image: I got this]

% code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, patterns}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}


\definecolor{titlecolor}{RGB}{199,232,250}

\newcommand{\titlecurve}{
  \fill[titlecolor,ultra thick]
  ($(title.south west) +(-1pt,-1pt)$) -- ($(title.north west)+(0pt,-1pt)$) coordinate(A)
  to[curve to,out=90,in=180]  ($(A)+(5pt,5pt)$)
  -- ($(title.north east)+(-5pt,0pt)$) coordinate(B)
  to[curve to,out=0,in=90] ($(B)+(6pt,-5pt)$) coordinate(C)
      --($(C)+(-0.5pt,-5pt)$) coordinate(D)
      to[curve to,out=-90,in=0] ($(D)+(-5pt,-10pt)$) coordinate(F)
      -- cycle;
    }

\newtcolorbox{oenv}{
  enhanced,
  boxrule=3pt,
  title=Temp title,%
  colframe=titlecolor,
  colback=white,
  coltitle=red,
  attach boxed title to top right={xshift=10pt, yshift=1pt},
  boxed title style={empty},
  underlay boxed title=\titlecurve

}

\begin{document}

\begin{oenv}
  Let $f$ be defined by 
\end{oenv}


\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just shift the coordinates, but I'd like to argue that rotating them around the center of the title box looks better. And `rounded corners` spares you from adding all these arcs by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, patterns}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}


\definecolor{titlecolor}{RGB}{199,232,250}

\newcommand{\titlecurve}{
  \path ([yshift=-2pt]title.south west) -- (title.north east) coordinate[pos=-0.1] (BL)
  coordinate[pos=1.1] (TR);
  \path ([yshift=-2pt]title.south east) -- (title.north west) coordinate[pos=-0.1] (BR)
  coordinate[pos=1.1] (TL);
  \fill[titlecolor,ultra thick,rounded corners]
  ([rotate around={-5:(title.center)}]BL) -- 
  ([rotate around={-5:(title.center)}]TL) -- 
  ([rotate around={-5:(title.center)}]TR) --
  ([rotate around={-5:(title.center)}]BR) -- cycle;
    }

\newtcolorbox{oenv}{
  enhanced,
  boxrule=3pt,
  title=Temp title,%
  colframe=titlecolor,
  colback=white,
  coltitle=red,
  attach boxed title to top right={xshift=10pt, yshift=1pt},
  boxed title style={empty},
  underlay boxed title=\titlecurve

}

\begin{document}

\begin{oenv}
  Let $f$ be defined by 
\end{oenv}


\end{document}
```

[image]

With one sharp corner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, patterns}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}


\definecolor{titlecolor}{RGB}{199,232,250}

\newcommand{\titlecurve}{
  \path ([yshift=-2pt]title.south west) -- (title.north east) coordinate[pos=-0.1] (BL)
  coordinate[pos=1.1] (TR);
  \path ([yshift=-2pt]title.south east) -- (title.north west) coordinate[pos=-0.1] (BR)
  coordinate[pos=1.1] (TL);
  \fill[titlecolor,ultra thick,rounded corners]
  ([rotate around={-5:(title.center)}]BL) -- 
  ([rotate around={-5:(title.center)}]TL) -- 
  ([rotate around={-5:(title.center)}]TR) --
  ([rotate around={-5:(title.center)}]BR) -- ([rotate around={-5:(title.center)}]BL);
    }

\newtcolorbox{oenv}{
  enhanced,
  boxrule=3pt,
  title=Temp title,%
  colframe=titlecolor,
  colback=white,
  coltitle=red,
  attach boxed title to top right={xshift=10pt, yshift=1pt},
  boxed title style={empty},
  underlay boxed title=\titlecurve

}

\begin{document}

\begin{oenv}
  Let $f$ be defined by 
\end{oenv}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it possible to make the title.south west corner sharp ? (like in the desired picture)

Comment: @Clifford Sure, just replace `cycle` by `([rotate around={-5:(title.center)}]BL)`. The corresponding corner for the orange box is covered by the bigger box, so it is hard to see that this corner is sharp.